# How to get Page Notifications through Google+ API

Tags: google-plus

Is there a way to get a list of all Private/Public Page notifications through the Google+ API?

for example, the notifications that you see on this page from your browser: `https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/{YOUR_PAGE_ID_HERE}/notifications/all`

I can only see the ability to get `Public` activities through the API.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not currently available. See (and star) https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=96 to register your support for such a feature.